# Arabic text displays ?????????????? in webpage

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress site (Arabic). It shows arabic text  in home page. but when I include footer page the Arabic text in footer shows ?????. Arabic  text is displaying properly in my home page. Problem occurs on included page.I have included

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type"  CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=iso-8859-6">
```

in my inluded footer page. But no luck.Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Meta tags should be in the header! Please provide an example file, it is very likely that the encoding is wrong.

Comment: http://www.ar-php.org/faq-php-arabic.html

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. The charset wasn't the problem. my text editor dreamweaver was the problem.  I  created a new PHP page and  copied the same code and saved,its properly working.

Answer (score 0):

You must use UTF-8 in footer as well

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I think this is included in header file but not in footer, so include this meta tag in footer file as well.

Comment: Yes,I included it in both home page and header page